# Same input keeps adding to the arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm writing a number guessing game in java.
Number guessing game is a numeric version of famous hangman, where computer picks a
number between a prespecified range and user has to guess that number.
Requirements:

1. User must guess a number between 0-1000 and tells the user the range of guessed
   number.
2. User has max 10 guesses.
3. Every time user makes a guess, total guesses reduce by one.
4. Computer keeps track of all the numbers user has guessed so far and shows this
   information before next guess.
5. If the guess is correct, game ends in a win. In case of incorrect guess, computer gives a
   hint to the user. If the user guess is greater than the picked number, then client tell the
   user that ‘your guess is bigger’ and in case of being smaller appropriate message is
   shown.
6. In case of invalid guess (alphabets, symbols and repeated guesses) one warning is given
   and on next warning user loses a guess

The following code is running fine but it always shows the same number after guesses number. I think its not adding the new input in the arrraylist rather the first one everytime.

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class NumberGuess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int tries = 10;
        ArrayList<Integer> guessed = new ArrayList();
        int warnings = 2;
        int i = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(1000);
        private void StartMenu () {
            System.out.println("\" Welcome to the Number guessing game!\n I am thinking of a number between 0-1000\n You have 1 warning.\n You have 1 warning.\n ------------ ");
        }

        public char[] ToCharacterArray (String input){
            char arr[] = new char[input.length()];
            arr = input.toCharArray();
            return arr;

        }

        public boolean CheckInput ( char arr[]){
            if (Character.isDigit(arr[0])) {
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }


        String input;

        while (tries > 0 && warnings > 0) {
            System.out.println("You have " + tries + " guesses left.");
            if (tries == 10) {
                System.out.println("guessed number: ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("guessed number: ");
                for (Integer a : guessed) {
                    System.out.println(guessed.get(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Please guess a number:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            input = sc.next();

            char InputString[] = ToCharacterArray(input);
            if (CheckInput(InputString)) {
                int intInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
                guessed.add(intInput);
                if (intInput > random) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is greater");
                }
                if (intInput < random) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is smaller");
                }
                if (intInput == random) {
                    System.out.println("Congrats! You win.");
                    System.out.println("The guessed number is: " + intInput);
                    tries = -1;
                }

            }
            tries--;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never change `i` as you loop over the items. so you're going to always print the same element.

Comment: *"The following code is running fine"* – Nope, it isn't. You currently have a method within a method, which is not allowed in Java. This code does not compile.

Comment: `for (Integer a : guessed) { System.out.println(guessed.get(i)); }` This doesn't make any sense. Either use an enhanced for loop or a C-style for loop. If you had narrower variable scopes (i.e. short methods) instead of one giant main method, it would be harder to misuse variables like this and not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you iterate over the guessed numbers, and then print out the item of index i from that list. The number i at that point will always be zero, so it will always print just the first element from that list. Instead, you can just print the a, that is the element itself, after the iteration on guessed. Here is how it will look like:

```
System.out.println("guessed number: ");
for (Integer a : guessed) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```